# Audio Classification with Counter

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, audio-recognition

I'm trying to create a model that can identify one particular sound, and every time it hears that sound, it increases a counter by 1. So for example, if it hears a specific bird chirping ten times, the counter should display the number 10.

I'm looking for a bit of guidance here as to how to go about this. I know that I will need to use audio classification and for my data, I only have .wav files of that one particular sound since I recorded them with my iPhone. Currently, I'm just preprocessing the data and doing some EDA with librosa in Python.

**Here's my questions:**

**1. Is there a way to train a model to only identify one particular sound based on the data I have? (and if it hears anything different, it's classified as 0/no)**

**2. How would I go about combining the audio classification model (given that it works) with a counter that can capture a real time sound, process it and display a number if its that particular sound?**

I don't really know where to start when I think about these questions. Any help regarding what libraries I may need, terms I should research or know regarding sound/audio data or just your own personal opinion on how you would tackle this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of sound you are describing, that have a well defined duration and can be counted, is called a sound event. The task of detecting such is called *Sound Event Detection* (SED). Sometimes one also sees it called Audio Event Detection or Acoustic Event Detection (AED).

There are some resources for learning about it online, for example:

- [Sound Event Detection using Machine Learning (EuroPython 2021)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrhsFfCOL-s)
- [Sound Event Detection: A Tutorial](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05463)

The key to doing this in real-time, is to process the audio as many short, fixed length analysis windows. Say that your model takes 1 second of audio as input, then you would every 0.1 second (for example) give it the last 1 second of audio, make a classification, and process that.